# How are nested bounding boxes handled in object detection (and in particular in the case of the SSD)?

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, object-detection, non-max-suppression, single-shot-multibox-detector

The basic approach to non-maximum-suppression makes sense, but I am kind of confused about how you handle nested bounding boxes.

Suppose you have two predicted boxes, with one completely enclosing another. What happens under this circumstance (in particular, in the case of the Single Shot MultiBox Detector)? Which bounding box do you select?